# Does Android JobService need to be exported?

Tags: android

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html

I am implementing an Android JobService, but I am confused whether it needs the `"android:exported=true"` attribute in the manifest or not.

There's little information on this in the Google documentation.
Some resources on the web, such as the answer here says it needs it.

[how to call service in background, when application is close, that time continues work service and call api ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427120/how-to-call-service-in-background-when-application-is-close-that-time-continue/43465686#43465686)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/JobScheduler/Content) is one of several that I have that demonstrate the use of `JobScheduler`. There is no `android:exported="true"` or any `<intent-filter>` elements on the `<service>` elements:

```
<service
  android:name=".DemoJobService"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

You do need that `android:permission` attribute, though.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that was the case because it's counterintuitive that the Android system cannot access a JobService without the exported attribute.