# why my JobService is not working in some devices?

Tags: java, android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

i'm creating and app which notify the user in some specific period of time, i used JobService to let it working automatically and with the app closed, my problem is... there are some devices that my Job simply does not start, i dont know what is happing, because in my cellphone it works nice, but in some of my friends' devices, it doesn't.

I'm sending my JobService's class

```
package com.medicina.mednews;


public class JobServiceNotification extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = "JobServiceNotification ";
    private boolean jobCancelled = false;
    String android_id;
    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference, refJob;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job started");
        doBackgroundWork(params);

        return true;
    }

    private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                reference= db.getReference().child("Usuarios").child(android_id).child("NoticiasDoPython");
                refJob = db.getReference().child("Usuarios").child(android_id).child("JobServiceFinished");




                reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        PrincipalModel principalModell3=snapshot.getValue(PrincipalModel.class);
                        Log.i("G3",""+principalModell3);
                        Log.i("GT",snapshot.getKey());
                        String aa = principalModell3.getData();
                        String[] aaS = aa.split(" ");
                        String idNotification = aaS[4];
                        idNotification = idNotification.replace(":","");
                        Log.i("IdNotification",idNotification);

                        addNotification(principalModell3.getTitulo(),principalModell3.getDescrição(),idNotification);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                   copyFirebaseData();
                   Log.i("Execução","Executei = "+i);
                    if (jobCancelled) {
                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Job finished");
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                Date date = new Date();
                Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                refJob.child(dateFormat.format(date)).setValue(""+currentTime);
                jobFinished(params, false);

            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before completion");

        jobCancelled = true;
        return true;
    }

    public void copyFirebaseData() {
        android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);


        DatabaseReference questionNodes = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child(android_id).child("NoticiasDoPython");
        final DatabaseReference toUsersQuestions = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child(android_id).child("NoticiasMovidasPeloAndroid");

        questionNodes.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot questionCode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String KeyChild = questionCode.getKey();
                  Log.i("KEYYY",KeyChild);
                    String DateAntiga = questionCode.child("Data").getValue(String.class);
                    String DescricaoAntiga = questionCode.child("Descrição").getValue(String.class);
                    String TituloAntiga = questionCode.child("Titulo").getValue(String.class);
                    String LinkAntiga = questionCode.child("Link").getValue(String.class);
                    String ImagemAntiga = questionCode.child("Imagem").getValue(String.class);
                    String Id = questionCode.child("IdNoticia").getValue(String.class);

                    toUsersQuestions.child(KeyChild).child("Id").setValue(Id);
                    toUsersQuestions.child(KeyChild).child("Imagem").setValue(ImagemAntiga);
                    toUsersQuestions.child(KeyChild).child("Data").setValue(DateAntiga);
                    toUsersQuestions.child(KeyChild).child("Descrição").setValue(DescricaoAntiga);
                    toUsersQuestions.child(KeyChild).child("Link").setValue(LinkAntiga);
                    toUsersQuestions.child(KeyChild).child("Titulo").setValue(TituloAntiga);

                    questionNodes.child(KeyChild).removeValue();



                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }




    private void addNotification(String titleNot,String DescriptNot, String idNotification) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default", "Channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_nuvem_deletar)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentTitle(titleNot)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(DescriptNot))

                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentText(DescriptNot);
        builder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //ESTAMOS DEFININDO UM ID ALEATÓRIO PARA GERAR MÚLTIPLAS NOTIFICAÇÕES
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long millisecondOfDay =
                TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) +
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) +
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND)) +
                        cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

        manager.notify(Integer.parseInt(idNotification), builder.build()); //IREMOS DEFINIR UM ID COM UUID, MAS DEPOIS TEREMOS QUE MUDAR POIS ISSO NÃO ESTÁ CERTO !!! POSSIVELMENTE TEREMOS QUE IR PRO JSON
        //ESTAMOS DEFININDO UM ID ALEATÓRIO PARA GERAR MÚLTIPLAS NOTIFICAÇÕES
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

    <application
        android:name=".FirebaseHandler"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Mednews"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <receiver
            android:name=".StartReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".JobServiceNotification"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MedMenu.activity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried to use the normal JobService class, but it simply doesn't work in some specific devices, the result is that my notifications don't start

Comment: Please post your manifest too.

Comment: @JonR85 Hi Jon, i just posted it, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351255/does-android-jobservice-need-to-be-exported

Comment: Looks like you might need: android:exported="true" in your manifest

Comment: Sorry, here's a better reference question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325618/jobservice-does-not-require-android-permission-bind-job-service-permission

Comment: @JonR85 Hi Jon, i just tried it but stills not working, the app starts but the Job not